# React useRef remains null in test environment but gets set in browser

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite, react-testing-library, vitest

I am having an issue with @testing-library/react where my React ref remains null in my test environment even though it gets set without issue in my browser. Is this expected and if so is there a way I can mock the reference to work properly? I have been trying to look around but haven't found a lot of answers.

As the radioGroupValue updates and the useEffect gets called `rgRef.current` is consistently null.

Package.json

```
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "vite": "^4.3.2",
    "vitest": "^0.31.0"
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.7",
```

Code example (the reason for using a ref this way is to get around a limitation in mui)

```
  const rgRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  const [radioGroupValue, setRadioGroupValue] = useState<string>(
    filterOptions[0].value
  );

  const handleSearchFilter = useCallback(
    (searchValue: string) => {
      if (!rgRef.current) {
        console.log('Ref did not get set.');
        return {};
      }
      const actualGroupValue =
        Array.from(rgRef.current.getElementsByTagName('input')).find((e) => {
          return e.checked;
        })?.value ?? radioGroupValue;
      return actualGroupValue ? { [actualGroupValue]: searchValue } : {};
    },
    [radioGroupValue]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <RadioGroup
        row
        ref={rgRef} ...
```

I have tried setting the ref in different ways including trying to assign a value directly to .current without any success. I have tried to do my research to see if I need to somehow mock refs with also very little success, what I did find was people using react-test-renderer recommending @testing-library/react when facing this issue with refs.

Answer (score 1):

Your React ref remains null in your test environment is because refs are not actually created until the component is rendered. In your test environment, the component is not actually rendered, so the ref is never created.

To mock the ref to work properly, you can use the `act()` function from `@testing-library/react`. The `act()` function allows you to simulate user interaction with your component, including rendering the component.

Here is an example of how you can use the `act()` function to mock the ref:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { act } from "@testing-library/react";

const rgRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
const [radioGroupValue, setRadioGroupValue] = useState<string>(
  filterOptions[0].value
);

const handleSearchFilter = useCallback(
  (searchValue: string) => {
    if (!rgRef.current) {
      console.log("Ref did not get set.");
      return {};
    }
    const actualGroupValue =
      Array.from(rgRef.current.getElementsByTagName("input")).find((e) => {
        return e.checked;
      })?.value ?? radioGroupValue;
    return actualGroupValue ? { [actualGroupValue]: searchValue } : {};
  },
  [radioGroupValue]
);

const App = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    // Simulate user clicking on the radio button
    act(() => {
      rgRef.current.querySelector("input[value='option2']").click();
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <RadioGroup
        row
        ref={rgRef}
        value={radioGroupValue}
        onChange={handleClick}
      >
        <Radio value="option1">Option 1</Radio>
        <Radio value="option2">Option 2</Radio>
      </RadioGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

it("should set the ref when the component is rendered", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  expect(wrapper.find("RadioGroup").ref.current).toBeTruthy();
});
```

We use the `act()` function to simulate the user clicking on the radio button. This causes the ref to be set, and the test passes.

Comment: I guess the answer you give is not too clear, you were using functions that are not defined and I dont think your example will work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem exactly because I do not see how you are setting up your tests and how you render the component in your test.

The philosophy behind Testing Library is that you write your tests in the closest way possible to how a user would interact with them.

To give you something to start with, my tests these days usually look something like this:

```js
import { describe, expect, beforeAll, it } from "vitest";
import { cleanup, fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";

describe("MyComponent", () => {

 beforeAll(() => {
    cleanup();
  });

  it("displays the shuffler component", () => {
    // Arrange
    render(<MyComponent />);

    // Act
    const button = await screen.findByRole("button", { name: /Text on button/gi });
    fireEvent.click(button);    

    // Assert
    expect(screen.findByText("Text on page, which is only rendered after button click"));
  });
```

I suspect that there is something wrong with your test setup or how you are using React Testing Library. It's hard to know without any more details about the test itself.

Make sure that you are using the `render` method from React Testing Library, and that you are only using their API, don't mix with vanilla JavaScript or just randomly wrap things in `act`. The maintainers of React Testing Libraries are taking care of using the `act` method for you.

Also, make sure you have the latest version of Testing Library and the any related packages, since there were a couple of important bug fixes in `@testing-library/react` version `14.0.0`.